# Displaying matplotlib charts in groupbox in PyQT5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am trying to use radio buttons to change the content of a groupbox.  I have the radio buttons printing to the console right now, but would like them to display a matplotlib chart. I'm not even sure where to start to change the content of a groupbox. I've tried googling, and haven't found much useful.

I'll post an example of one.

The actual button:

```
 self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.exangRadio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.exangRadio.setObjectName("exangRadio")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exangRadio, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.exangRadio.toggled.connect(self.updateGraph)
```

Selecting the correct output

```
def updateGraph(self, checked):
    if not checked:
        return
    elif self.exangRadio.isChecked():
        visuals.exangChart()
```

The "chart" function

```
def exangChart():
    print('exang')
```

I haven't actually written the charts yet, just trying to get the hang of how to display anything in the groupbox.

Answer (score 2):

Adding content to group boxes works exactly the same as adding child widgets to any other widget. For example, this will create a group box containing a label and a button

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

group_box = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('my groupbox')

label = QtWidgets.QLabel('This is a label')
button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('This is a button')

# set layout of group box and add widgets to layout
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(group_box)
layout.addWidget(label)
layout.addWidget(button)

group_box.show()
app.exec()
```